# 360 ImageView Rotation - Speed based on userValues

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer

I have a view which users can key in some values into six textview boxes, which later get saved into a plist. My next view has a imageview which has a circle I designed. I am want to animate this circle with a 360 rotation based on how many textfields have values.

If the user types values for one textfield it goes at 1x speed.
If the user types values for two textfield it goes at 2x speed.
etc.

Can anyone please tell me how I can create this clockwise rotated animation of my imageView with a speed which is set based on the textfields which have values. All values are stored within the p.list. The animation needs to be on infinite too.

Thanks Guys,

Answer (score 1):

You use the `animateWithDuration: animations: completion:` to animate `UIView` objects.

It is used like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^(void)animations 
completion:^(BOOL finished)completion];
```

Inside the `animations` block you enter the animation you want like for example in your case

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*2); // This will rotate it 360 degrees
```

And to make it infinite you can add this method inside a function and in the `completion` block you call that function to make it infinite.

Comment: I tried the following but it never seemed to work :  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        
        self.accuracyWheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*2);
    
        completion:^(BOOL finished)self.accuracyWheel];